# What's the differences between tf.contrib.slim.conv2d and tf.contrib.layers.conv2d?

Tags: python, tensorflow

It looks like they have the same parameters.and i can't find  tf.contrib.slim.conv2d in tensorflow official documents, it makes me really confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.contrib.slim.conv2d is tf.contrib.layers.conv2d)  # True
```

The reason they both exist is likely historical, and to support backwards compatibility - i.e. it probably existed in `tf.contrib.slim`, then was moved to `tf.contrib.layers`. Removing it from `tf.contrib.slim` would have broken existing models however, so I imagine the code has been ported to `tf.contrib.layers` and there's a line in `slim` somewhere that creates an alias - something like

```
conv2d = tf.contrib.layers.conv2d
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i am a newcomer to tensorflow,sorry for asking some basic questions like this.

Comment: No worries. A lot of stuff in tensorflow doesn't make sense until you realize the history behind it (and there's no evidence of the history behind most of it based on the documentation alone).